# How can I assign variables names to each list elements?

Tags: r

I have a list of 6 tibbles and a vector containing 6 variable names. I am trying to assign a variable names to each tibbles.

I can do it by extracting a list element and assign to a variable name.

```r
files <- c('sat_results', 'ap_2010', 'class_size', 'demographics', 'graduation', 'hs_directory')
file_names <- paste0(files, '.csv')
fileTb <- map(file_names, read_csv) 
sat_results <- fileTb[[1]]
```

How can I do it with a loop or map?

Comment: try `?mget`, `?assign`

Comment: Thanks. I finally figured it out. I'm using a `for` loop and `assign` function.

Comment: feel free to post the solution to your own problem as an answer: this is encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can add names to a list by using the `names()` function.

```
names(YourList) <- c(Vector with names)
```

Example:

```
x = as.list(1:5)

names(x) <- LETTERS[1:5]
```

Comment: Thanks. But it only gives name to each element. This does not assign variable names to each list element.

Comment: I see. I know it's not my business, but what difference does it make for you whether you call x[["object"]] as an element of a list or object as an object in the .GlobalEnv?

Answer (score 0):

Solution I came up with `Ben Bolker` help.

```r
files <- c('sat_results', 'ap_2010', 'class_size', 'demographics', 'graduation', 'hs_directory')
file_names <- paste0(files, '.csv')
fileTb <- map(file_names, read_csv) 

for (n in 1:length(files)) {
  assign(files[n], fileTb[[n]])
}
```

I prefer to use `map` rather than using a `for` loop. I couldn't figure it out.